# JFreeChart: set minimum X-tick interval in the chart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I need to set minimum X-tick interval in the chart. I have a dataset that contains 1000 entries, i.e. `<0,12>,<5,22>,<10,23>,...,<1000,20>`. In dataset, the interval between X-values is equal to 5. In the chart I want to set X-tick interval equal to 100.

I use this code, but it does not work:

```
    NumberAxis range = (NumberAxis)plot.getRangeAxis();  
    range.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(100));
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
    private JFreeChart createChart(CategoryDataset dataset) 
    {

        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createAreaChart(
            this.title,
            "Time", 
            "Net demand", 
            dataset,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
            true,
            true,
            false
        );

        Title t = new TextTitle(this.subtitle);
        chart.addSubtitle(t);

        int transparency = 95;
        Color c = new Color(1, 158, 115, transparency);
        final CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
        CategoryItemRenderer renderer = new CustomRenderer(c);
        renderer.setSeriesOutlinePaint(0, Color.black);
        renderer.setSeriesOutlineStroke(0, new BasicStroke(0.5f));
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0,c);
        plot.setRenderer(renderer);

        NumberAxis range = (NumberAxis)plot.getRangeAxis();  
        range.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(60));  

        return chart;    
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've set the tick unit for the range axis, which is the y-axis in JFreeChart.  For the x-axis, you want the domain axis.

```
NumberAxis xAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();  
xAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(60));
```

The **domain** and **range** terms come from a function mapping a set of domain values to a set of range values.  With hindsight, using getXAxis() and getYAxis() for the method names would have been clearer for most people...for JFreeChart 2 I'll probably change it.

Comment: Thanks. In this case I receive the compilation error: Cannot cast from CategoryAxis to NumberAxis

Comment: Do I need to override refreshTicks() in NumberAxis?

Comment: No, I didn't notice you were using a CategoryPlot, I assumed it was an XYPlot.  Since your x-values are numerical, you should try using an XYAreaChart.

Comment: @DavidGilbert Can you please help in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48833471/jfreechart-stackedbarchart