# JFreeChart StackedBarChart

Tags: java, jfreechart, java-2d

I am drawing a stackedbarchart. Now for the x-axis i have labels which are auto generated based on CategoryDataset. I want to show these labels with intervals because otherwise they are overlapped in case i have large number of values for the dataset.

But I am not able to understand how to achieve this. For example i have this following code.

```
CategoryDataset dataset = getDataset();
final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart(
                graphTitle, xAxisTitle, yAxisTitle,
                dataset, orientation, legend, toolTips, urls);
CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
```

Now how can i add x-axis labels in intervals that is I don't want a label for each column rather after each 5 columns.